# Does WP8 support to read video from media library?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there have a way to read video(s) from media library on Windows Phone 8? As you know, WP7 only supports read pictures via MediaLibrary class. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the same in Windows Phone 8 you can check this link :

[What can we do with MediaLibrary in Windows 8 Phone](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/acaa4a59-d300-4442-9c2d-3ca794968220/)

and this :

[What MediaLibrary needs/is missing (Windows Phone)](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2012/09/what-medialibrary-needsis-missing.html)

Comment: How is whatsapp doing it