# Video playback of a file stored in Media Library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there an API which supports playback of Video files which are stored in the Media Library on a Windows Phone 8?

Until now I have only been able to find the option of playback from Isolated storage as mentioned on the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394041(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to access videos stored in the Media Library :

From StackOverflow :

- [So there is no way to access videos on Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873874/so-there-is-no-way-to-access-videos-on-windows-phone-8)
- [Windows Phone 8: Media file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access/13473349#13473349)
- [Does WP8 support to read video from media library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860293/does-wp8-support-to-read-video-from-media-library)

From MSDN :

MSDN lists all the things that can be done with MediaLibrary in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary), (Images, Music and its metadata). But read-only access of videos is not part of it.
If it was, no doubt that MS would have mentioned it in this [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple answers in the following thread which points out it is now feasible to read the video files via KnownFolders if you upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1: [Windows Phone 8: Media file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access)

Here is an alternative option for accessing the videos (also in Windows Phone 8.1):

```
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

Once you have the file you should be able to play it back.