# Include video for playback in xap file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I require to include a video file for playback in xap file, instead of separately uploading it in Isolated Storage.

What are my options?

Originally I had wanted to play a video file from the MediaLibrary.
[Video playback of a file stored in Media Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480405/video-playback-of-a-file-stored-in-media-library/19480792?noredirect=1#19480792)

As I learnt, it is not possible to do so. Hence, I am exploring the option of at least including the video file inside xap file.

Kindly note that the API for video playback supports reading video files only from Isolated storage,  hence I can't just include it in the project and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your video is located inside assets folder (in your .xap file) the following should work:

```
    private void PlayVideo()
    {
        var mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher
        {
            Media = new Uri("Assets/video.mp4", UriKind.Relative),
            Location = MediaLocationType.Install,
            Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop,
            Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape
        };
        mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a resource as you add images to your project. Solution explorer.